The Beta Spectrum of Sr-90
I experimented the beta decay of Sr-90 using the magnetic deflection method. After fitting it using the equation
$$\Gamma(E_e) \propto \sqrt{E_e^2-m_e^2c^4}(Q-E_e)^2E_e$$
and found that $Q = 2.81 \, \text{MeV}$. But if we look at the decay scheme of Sr-90, we see individual decay energy of less than $Q$ above. I don't understand how to make sense of this. I know that the sum of of these decay energy add up to approximately $Q = 2.81 \, \text{MeV}$ but it seems to be contradictory since no electron have this much energy.

Your spectrometer should see electrons drawn from both the half-MeV strontium spectrum and the two-MeV yttrium spectrum. Are you fitting your combined spectrum to this single curve? Can you share your data?

Why are you using that particular fitting equation? Maybe it is correct, but I really doubt it is.
